# Where and how I find the songs in iphone 5 which were downloaded into itunes

Tags: itunes

Can someone help me with this. As I am new to iPhone and itunes. I have couple of songe (audio format) downloaded from internet and added into "My Music" in itunes. I have synced my iphone 5 with itunes in my PC. But on iPhone where these songs would have been downloaded?? When I go to the itunes tab on iphone 5 it takes me straight to it main page and if I go the downloaded ones then that one is empty.

Comment: Which format are these songs in (MP3, WAV, AAC etc)? Did you either select "Sync all music" or selected the songs for syncing?

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes app on the iPhone is for browsing the iTunes *store*. The Downloads tab there only shows you songs that are currently being downloaded from the store. If I understand correctly, you're tapping this:

[image: iTunes.app]

Check the **Music** app on the phone instead - synced music should show up there:

[image: Music.app]